# PDF for $X$ when $-X$ is distributed according to $f(x)$.

Tags: probability

I've seen several problems in probability where it talks about $-X$ being distributed according to $f(x)$, and part of the problem involves finding the PDF for $X$. In one such case, it was stated that $-X$ has an exponential distribution. Doesn't this automatically mean that $X$ also has an exponential distribution distribution as well? In general, does $X$ and $-X$ always have the same distribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $-X$ has cdf $F$, $f=F^\prime$ so $X$ has CDF $P(X\le x)=P(-X\ge-x)=1-F(-x)$. Its PDF is the $x$-derivative $f(-x)$. So $X,\,-X$ have the same distribution if $f$ is an even function. An exponential distribution doesn't satisfy this; in fact, it's bounded below, so after a sign change is instead bounded above.

Comment: You mean "its PDF is the x-derivative" of $F(-x)$, right?

Comment: @student010101 Not quite: the $x$-derivative, $f(-x)$, of $1-F(-x)$.